# Can an ActiveRecord before_save filter halt the save without halting the transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way for a before_save filter to halt the entire save without halting the transaction? What I'm trying to do is have a "sample" version of my model that the user can interact with and save but the changes themselves are never actually saved. The following will halt the transaction and (naturally) return false when I call @model.update_attributes:

```
before_filter :ignore_changes_if_sample
def ignore_changes_if_sample
  if self.sample?
    return false
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's precisely what's happening here. If you look at your SQL, you should be seeing BEGIN and then COMMIT, without anything between them. The before_save is not halting the transaction; it's simply preventing the record from being saved by returning false.

To more generally answer your question, records that fail to persist do not halt transactions unless they also raise an exception. Exceptions trigger the ROLLBACK that prevents any part of the transaction from being committed. So even if you return false here, a larger, overarching transaction should continue just fine.

You can read more about transactions and how Rails uses them in the [ActiveRecord::Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) documentation.

Comment: I'm seeing that it does rollback the transaction though.